# Error en la salida por cout de los argumentos de main

Tags: c++

Buenas tarde;
Tengo un bucle para sacar los argumentos de main que se han utilizado en la línea de comandos, sin embargo, después de sacarlos, los siguientes cout no se muestran. Tengo entendido que cout con << recibe variables referencia. Si intento sacar el argumento argv[argc] que debe ser null (como se indica en, por ejemplo Stroustrup "El lenguaje de programación c++" Ed. Especial Punto 6.1.7 Pag. 122), los siguientes cout no salen. Parece ser que el último parámetro (null == argv[argc]) invalida por algún motivo a cout.
Pongo un sencillo código en el que no se muestra Fin Adios.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout<<"Numero de parametros: "<<argc<<"\n";
    for (int i=0; i<=argc; i++)  // Aqui si ponemos argc-1  si sale bien
        cout<<"valor de "<<i<<": "<<argv[i];
    cout<<"\nFin\n";
    cout<<"Adios\n";
    return 0;
}
```

¿Alguien podría indicarme que carácter o variable manda a cout la ultima salida que hace quede la salida de cout bloqueada?

Comment: tiene errores de comilacion: `;` en `cout<<"Numero de parametros: "<<argc<<"\n"`

Comment: Stroustrup: "La lista de parámetros termina en cero; es decir, argv[argc]==0. Para la orden: miprograma.exe uno dos tres muestra argv[0]=miprograma.exe argv[1]=uno argv[2]=dos argv[3]=tres argv[4]=   teniendo a argv[4]==argv[argc]

Comment: Gracias Daniel. Resto creo que va bien excepto por lo expuesto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparte de lo que te indican en los comentarios (el *punto-y-coma* omitido y el valor máximo de `argc` ), lo que ocurre es que `std::basic_ostream` **no soporta** el envío de punteros a caracteres con valor NULL ( o `nullptr` ). Es lo que se conoce como **comportamiento indefinido**.

Eso quiere decir que el comportamiento ante esa circunstancia **depende de la implementación**; algunos compiladores harán lo que indicas; otros, pueden directamente generar un error de protección general, errores de segmento, o cualquier otra cosa.

Resumiendo: **no** intentes usar `cout` para mostrar punteros a cadenas con valor NULL.

Observa que ese comportamiento **no ocurre** para punteros `void *` con valor NULL. En ese caso, su valor se muestra correctamente.

Comment: dónde podría ampliar la información sobre std::basic_osteam y los valores que puede soportar. Entonces, la idea de que cout junto con << solo admite valores referencia es correcta aunque imprecisa. ¿verdad?. Gracias.

Comment: Suelo utilizar estas 2 páginas, ambas en ingles: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) y [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/). La [referencia oficial](https://www.iso.org/standard/50372.html) es de pago. También puedes consultar una lista de *recomendados* de SOen [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242).

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir con lo de `solo admite valores referencia`: `basic_ostream` soporta todos los tipos básicos, y algunas *cosillas* mas.

Comment: Quiero indicar que cuando se especifica cout<< el valor que debe aparecer en la derecha debe ser una referencia o algún dato que pueda convertirse a referencia ¿No?. ¿Dónde puedo profundizar en este tema de " std::basic_ostream no soporta el envío de punteros a caracteres con valor NULL ( o nullptr )?. Gracias

Comment: Jeje ... puedes empezar por [Google](https://www.google.es/search?q=basic_ostream+null+char+pointer&oq=basic_ostream+null+char+pointer). El primer resultado te lleva a una pregunta en SOen [Is printing a null-pointer Undefined Behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23283772) en la que indican incluso el apartado del estándar relevante. El resto de enlaces también te pueden servir.

Comment: @Dólmenes El estándar oficial es de pago, pero se dispone del borrador del mismo [de manera gratuita aquí](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf). Normalmente hay pocas diferencias entre el último borrador y la última versión aprobada.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Ah, no lo sabía. Yo los busco en Google. Siempre aparece alguno *por ahí*, en páginas ... de esas :-)

Comment: @Dólmenes Gracias por tu aporte. Todo esta establecido en el estándar ISO 14882-2011 (27.7.3.6.4). template<class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& out,
const char* s); y además se especifica claramente que: Requires: s shall not be a null pointer. También se especifica en el estándar (27.7.3.6.2) lo que indicas con void*: operator<<(const void* val);